# Estimate requests per second on an Apache server

Tags: apache-2.4, stress-testing

How can I get the average requests per second on an Apache 2.4 server based on the logs?

I'm trying to use k6 to load test a new server, a new cloud provider, with new hardware, but I don't know how to estimate how many users there are today.

Comment: Try with jmeter to make the load test. And use Summary results, graph results to analyze the results

Comment: A "user" can send dozens of hits, and some other users can send several more or just a few, users is generally not a good way to measure unless you have them all  authenticating and anonymous hits are not the ones you are after, then you can check the logs or log the users authenticating and filter them out from there. As general statistics though, you can get the amount of hits per second or minute you get, and [mod_status](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_status.html) gives you that  more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AWStats](https://awstats.sourceforge.io/) for apache logs. You can also use [Matomo (Piwik)](https://matomo.org/free-software/)  and [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com/) for create user oriented statistics.